# Python dict print One per line with Key in each line

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dict. like this

```
dict =
{0: ['a','b','c'],
 -0.75: ['a','b','c'],
.
.
.
}
```

I want to print this dict in the following format (one per line)

```
a 0
b 0
c 0
a -0.75
b -0.75
c -0.75
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
for k, v in dict.iteritems():
        for item in v:
            print item, k
```

Comment: @user1290757 Please suggest code improvements to answers via a comment rather than changing the answer. Your code could be incorrect or change the meaning of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, took so long and came to same conclusion, just modified the print a little: <br/>

       `print (str(item)+' '+str(key))`

Comment: @user1290757, there is not a variable named key in my original posted code. print (str(item)+' '+str(k)) would work .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for key,value in d.items():
    for val in value:
        print "%s --> %s"%(val,key)
```

The items() function will return a list of tuple, in this case

```
[(0, ['a', 'b', 'c']), (-0.75, ['a', 'b', 'c'])]
```

then we loop second time on this list, and get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for key, val in dict.items():
    for eachval in val:
        print eachval, key
```